# How do I call Amazon Fraud Detector from JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am getting an error that 'getEventPrediction' is not a function. I am following the AWS docs and can't figure out why.

Here's the docs I have followed:
`https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/FraudDetector.html`

This is the error I get when running a Lambda Test event:

> 2020-10-09T21:01:54.151Z   a5c86d6f-9347-49ec-9fe9-4124cd976953    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"frauddetector.getEventPrediction is not a function","stack":["TypeError: frauddetector.getEventPrediction is not a function","    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:18:18)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]}

This is the Lambda function:

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
    const frauddetector = new AWS.FraudDetector();
     
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
      frauddetector.getDetectors();
      console.log('getDetectors worked 3');
      
      var params = {
          detectorId: 'new_account_fraud_detector',
          eventId:'123456789',
          eventTimestamp: '2020-07-13T23:00:03Z',
          eventTypeName: 'new_customer_registration',
          eventVariables: {'email_address':'fake_jamie11@example.com', 'ip_address':'1.2.3.4'},
          entities: [ {entityType:'customer', entityId:'12345'} ]
      };  
    
      frauddetector.getEventPrediction(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
      });
      
        // TODO implement
       const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('FraudDetector : ran'),
        };
        return response;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK that is included with the Lambda runtime is not up to date with the latest Fraud Detector API changes.

GetEventPrediction was introduced in 2.720.0: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#27200

Lambda runtime is currently using 2.712.0: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is experiencing the same issues whereby the version of the aws-sdk in the lambda runtime is not the latest, following the advice in this post to create a custom layer is an easy solution:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-aws-sdk-latest-version/

The steps are:

- create a new directory and `cd` into it
- run `npm i aws-sdk`
- zip the cwd
- run the `aws lambda publish-layer-version` cli command